# pyLDAvis visualization from gensim not displaying the result in google colab

Tags: visualization, gensim, lda, pyldavis

```
import pyLDAvis.gensim
# Visualize the topics
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)
vis
```

The above code displayed the visualization of LDA model in google colab but then after reopening the notebook it stopped displaying.
I even tried
`pyLDAvis.display(vis, template_type='notebook')`
still not working

When I set

`pyLDAvis.enable_notebook(local=True)`

[image]

it does display the result but not the labels.. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 7):

when you install LDAvis make sure to specify the version to be 2.1.2 with:

```
!pip install pyLDAvis==2.1.2
```

the new versions don't seem to play well with colab.

Comment: Thank you ! I've been stuck for hours because colab doesnt have the right version

Answer (score 5):

they changed the package name. use it like:

```
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)
vis
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: @Shree kidding?! It's obvious! they changed the package name!

Comment: If they just mislabeled the package, then maybe it should be closed as a typo. But that's not obvious from your answer without any explanation. Take a look again at [answer]